# Characters entered twice in form field in modal dialog under safari 5.1

Tags: javascript, asp.net, safari

The below issue occurring only in Safari (v5.1.7). Works fine in IE & Firefox

I have asp.net page which just contains few asp textbox fields. If the page has been open via a call to window.showmodaldialog(), then each keypress in the input field results in the character appearing twice. e.g. if 4 is entered then it becomes 44 automatically. 
If opened via a call to window.open() or its an asp.net page(not opened as modal dialog), then text input is ok. 
This has started happening since upgrading Safari to v5.1.x (on windows 7).
What is causing this issue? What would be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is APPLE safari issue:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3404358?tstart=0

http://forums.techarena.in/technology-internet/1456224.htm

https://forums.zoho.com/topic/double-lleetteerrss-in-safari

Workaround Steps: though did not work for me

https://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/940269-double-letter-displayed-safari-browser

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3336946?start=0&tstart=0